# How to solve the error that is 'R CMD SHLIB'

Tags: r, powershell, dll

Run error example:

```
PS D:\Platanus\CiPA_Rocde\CiPA-master\AP_simulation\models> R CMD SHLIB newordherg_qNet.c
Invoke-History : 'SHLIB' It couldn't find location parameter permitting factor.  
Location line : 1 character : 1
+ R CMD SHLIB newordherg_qNet.c
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-History], 
ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeHistoryCommand
```

Although I find solution associated with R CMD SHLIB issue, it is difficult to solve the issue. Do you have any idea to solve error?

Comment: So did the solution solve the issue or not?

Comment: I didn't solve above error.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to have a workable example. What is in line 1 of the newordherg_qNet.c ? It should probably look something like the standard headers for R code -

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
```

I would check out Hadley's C page - http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#clang 
You could also check out using Rcpp to run C code that I've seen people do. 
Anyway hope it's helpful.

Comment: I already solved above problem. The error was just because of problem associated with system type in my PC. We need to confirm whether It was installed well or not , when installing R and Rstudio and R package. If someone has above error, I'd like to recommend to reinstall corresponding elements and reboot PC. Thank you for answering.